# How to handle custom Role Base Permissions with AWS Cognito

Tags: permissions, amazon-cognito, customization, roles

In AWS Cognito, We can manage Role Base Permissions for **AWS services**(S3 Bucket,EC2) with creating **GROUPS**. But How to mange **my own permission and Roles related to application for users** using Cognito User pool.

e.g.;

- Role =  MANAGER
- permissions = create-new-employee, update-employee

Is there is a solution for that in AWS Cognito User Pool?

Note: I want to mange my Front-End components which developed using ReactJs and Backend which developed using GraphQL + Spring boot according to permissions

I try to find any solution. But not found yet.